# R Boxplot From Filtered Data

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is formatted like the below:

```
| user_id | ans_id | key_name | prec_pause | trail_pause |
|---------|--------|----------|------------|-------------|
| 1       | 4      | Period   | 62.0       | 625.0       |
| 1       | 4      | Spacebar | 172.0      | 156.0       |
| 1       | 5      | Period   | 1235.0     | 218.0       |
| 1       | 5      | Spacebar | 218.0      | 141.0       |
| 1       | 8      | Comma    | 125.0      | 844.0       |
| 1       | 8      | Comma    | 129.0      | 800.0       |

## User-friendly form
dat <- structure(list(user_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ans_id = c(4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L), key_name = c("Period", "Spacebar", "Period", 
"Spacebar", "Comma", "Comma"), prec_pause = c(62, 172, 1235, 
218, 125, 129), trail_pause = c(625, 156, 218, 141, 844, 800)), .Names = c("user_id", 
"ans_id", "key_name", "prec_pause", "trail_pause"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I would like to create a box plot for each pair of pauses, so one pair for Period_prec_pause and one for Period_trail_pause. In the example above, there would be 3 such pairs.

Ideally, there would be extra spacing between pairs, but this is optional.

Comment: What type of plot are looking for?  A `boxplot` shows quantiles of continuous variables.  Are you trying for bars?

Comment: It should be a boxplot. It would show the quantiles of each "category", e.g. Period - prec_pause

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have enough data for each group to make those summaries.

Comment: This is just an example. My actual data frame has ~500k rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melt your data and boxplot it:

```
library (reshape2)
m = melt(dat[,c(3:5)])
boxplot(value ~ variable * key_name, data = m, col=(c("gold","darkgreen")))
```